# Let $f: G \to H $ be a group isomorphism. Show that for every $a \in G$, one has $o(f(a)) = o(a)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $ o(a)$ denote the order of $ a $ in a group $ G $. Let $f: G \to H $ be a group isomorphism. Show that for every $a \in G$, one has $o(f(a)) =o(a)$

Proof. Assume that $o(a) = n$ and that $ o (f (a))=m $. Since $ f $ is a homomorphism, we have $f (a)^n = f (a^n) = f (1_G) = 1_H$. Since $ m $ is the smallest positive integer such that $ f (a)^m = 1_H$, it follows that $m \leqslant n$. Similarly,  $f(1_G)=1_H=f (a)^m = f (a^m) $, and since $ f $ is injective, $ x^m = 1$, and so $ n \leqslant m. $ This shows that $ m = n $, and thus $o (f (a)) = o(a)$.

Is my proof correct? Any suggestions to fix it or improve it appreciated.

Comment: Injectivity of $f$ isn't in your hypotheses.

Comment: @Bernard fixed.

Comment: Proof looks good.

Comment: It is enough to suppose $f$ is an injective homomorphism.

Comment: When you wrote $f(1_H)$ I suspect you mean $1_H$

Comment: @Julien that is correct, I made the edit accordingly.

Comment: @Bernard Yes, since we do not need to assume that $f$ is surjective in order to complete the proof. I did not write the problem

Comment: The key idea of the proof is to show, when $f$ is injective: for any integer $k\ge1$, $a^k=1_G$ if and only if $f(a)^k = 1_H$. The statement about orders follows quickly from this.

Answer (score 1):

$\langle g \rangle$ is isomorphic to $\phi \langle g \rangle=\langle \phi(g) \rangle$